# STM32 freertos thread is not working

Tags: arm, eclipse-cdt, stm32, rtos, freertos

I am trying to implement a small freeRTOS project on Eclipse, by using gnuarmeclipse and openstm32 plugin ans STM32F411RE nucleo board.  Project is getting build and LED connected to PORT A pin 5 is blinking when the GPIO set and Reset functions are used inside main function.  But while using threads, its not working. here i am adding code.
Thank you for your valuable time.

```
    #include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include "cmsis_os.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_gpio.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_rcc.h"


static void StartThread(void const * argument);
static void SecondThread(void const * argument);
static void GPIO_Init2(void);

void Delay2(int);

#ifdef __GNUC__
  #define PUTCHAR_PROTOTYPE int __io_putchar(int ch)
#else
  #define PUTCHAR_PROTOTYPE int fputc(int ch, FILE *f)
#endif /* __GNUC__ */

int main(void)
{

    GPIO_Init2();

    /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
    osThreadDef(USER_Thread1, StartThread, osPriorityNormal, 0, configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE);
    osThreadDef(USER_Thread2, SecondThread, osPriorityNormal, 0, configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE);
    osThreadCreate (osThread(USER_Thread1), NULL);
    osThreadCreate (osThread(USER_Thread2), NULL);

    /* Start scheduler */
    osKernelStart();
  while (1){

  }

}
void Delay2(int nCount)

{

while(nCount--){
int a=5000;

while(a--){

}

}

}

void GPIO_Init2(void)
{
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA ,ENABLE);
        GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitDef;
        GPIO_InitDef.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_5;
        GPIO_InitDef.GPIO_Mode=GPIO_Mode_OUT;
        GPIO_InitDef.GPIO_OType=GPIO_OType_PP;
        GPIO_InitDef.GPIO_PuPd=GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
        GPIO_InitDef.GPIO_Speed=GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
        GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitDef);


            GPIO_SetBits(GPIOA,GPIO_Pin_5);
            osDelay(50);
            GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOA,GPIO_Pin_5);
            osDelay(100);


}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/* StartDefaultTask function */
static void StartThread(void const * argument)
{
  while(1) {
      GPIO_SetBits(GPIOA,GPIO_Pin_5);
      osDelay(500);
      GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOA,GPIO_Pin_5);
      osDelay(100);
      }

}

static void SecondThread(void const * argument)
{

        while(1) {

        }

}

#ifdef USE_FULL_ASSERT

/**
   * @brief Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
   * where the assert_param error has occurred.
   * @param file: pointer to the source file name
   * @param line: assert_param error line source number
   * @retval None
   */
void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
    ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */

}

#endif
```

Comment: osThreadDef, osThreadCreate, and osKernelStart are not part of the FreeRTOS API.  Are you really using FreeRTOS?  How are you intending for your two tasks to change between the Running and Blocked [states](http://www.freertos.org/RTOS-task-states.html)?  What does osDelay() do?  Should your tasks really have the same [priority](http://www.freertos.org/RTOS-task-priority.html)?  Are you using time slicing?  Does the RTOS kernel require a periodic tick source and have you configured a hardware timer to supply that tick?  It would probably be better to start with one of the FreeRTOS demo apps.

Comment: Thank you. I started with a demo again.
But getting error "undefined reference to vTaskDelay, xTaskCreate.
I cant find a batch file for stm32f4 for eclipse in demos folder. Please help me to solve this 

1. Created an STM3F411RE project in eclipse using openstm32 plugin

2. Copied freeRTOS folder from the project[link](https://github.com/henriqueprossi/stm32f4-discovery-freertos) including std periph library. 

3. deleted  main.c and replaced with hello_world.c in the other project. 

4. included FreeRTOS config header stm32f4xx_it.h from the same poject.

Comment: 5. included free rtos include path and CM4 path to c compiler and assembler include path.

6. Modified main code to remove dependency on discovery library.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `osDelay()` in `GPIO_Init2()` function because scheduler is not started yet (`osKernelStart()`).